# PL/SQL character variable

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

All Items in my table are 7 digits. If I input something with 6 digits should show 0 at the beginning. (output should be 7 digits.)

For example:

Input= 123456
Output= 0123456

How can I write it in Oracle SQL?

I've tried that. But it does not work.

```
cursor c1 is
into art_no_tmp1
select  art_no
from    barticles b
where   b.ean_no_1 = '789546584587';

cursor checklength is
into len_number
select length(art_no_tmp1)
from    dual;


if(len_number = 6) then
      return '0'+art_no_tmp1;
else
      return art_no_tmp1;
end if;
```

does anyone have an idea?

Comment: For future reference - the string concatenation operator in Oracle SQL and PL/SQL is `||`, not `+` - thus, you'd want to write `return '0' || ART_NO_TMP1;`.  Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`TO_CHAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions201.htm#i79330), with the leading `0` [format](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF51074):

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS (
  2     SELECT 1       num FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3     SELECT 12      num FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4     SELECT 123     num FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5     SELECT 1234    num FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  6     SELECT 12345   num FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  7     SELECT 123456  num FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  8     SELECT 1234567 num FROM DUAL
  9  )
 10  SELECT num, to_char(num, '0000000') FROM data;

       NUM TO_CHAR(NUM,'0000000')
---------- ----------------------
         1  0000001
        12  0000012
       123  0000123
      1234  0001234
     12345  0012345
    123456  0123456
   1234567  1234567
```

Comment: Thanx Vincent Malgrat... it has worked! 
have found also other way.. return '000'||art_no_tmp1;

Comment: @JagathBanneheka No you have not found other way - just use `to_char` as shown by Vincent.

Comment: Will this behave the same as my answer? truncating the string to the length in the second argument?

Comment: @roger I think the final function should raise an exception when the input is larger than 7 characters, whichever method is chosen. Silently truncating may make the caller think that everything went well. `LPAD` seems to give the same result as `TO_CHAR`, although it uses an implicit conversion if the input is of type number.

Comment: I agree: "Silently truncating may make the caller think that everything went well.". OP says all his data is 7 digits long, so his column is probably defined as `NUMBER(7)`.

Answer (score 3):

How about the [lpad](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/lpad.php) function?

```
LPAD('123', 7, '0') = '0000123'
```

Be careful though when the string is shorther than the length you want to fix.

Take a look at this example.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ae17/2

Comment: I'd go for the to_char method, as this involves an implicit to_char anyway.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Yeah, but when the length of the string gets bigger, it just sucks that it yields #######, take a look at the fiddle.